# Can I search for a file with a specific extension across all Bitbucket repositories?

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to find all occurrences of a file with a specific extension across all repositories available in Bitbucket. I have been struggling to find the answer to that on Google.

Let's say I am looking for all files ending with `.foo`

I would like to see a list of all repositories that contain such files. I would also like to be able to view paths within each repository to a specified file with an extension.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-search-syntax-814204781.html), you can add `ext:foo` to filter for files with the extension "foo".
You also have to add a search term, you can't just list files with a specific extension.